# AppDelegate access ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

In my xcode 9.2 swift 4 project i have two classes, one is `AppDelegate` where i handle all application specific functions (like subscribing and receiving push notifications) and ViewController (`Main.storyboard id is ShitstuffController`) where i handle my `WKWebView`

What i am trying to do is, when application is inactive or in background 
and user received and taps on local notification, open link received in that notification in my `ViewController's WKWebView`.

I am trying to access `ViewController` on tap like this

```
// AppDelegate.swift code
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShitstuffController")
controller.loadViewIfNeeded();

print(controller);
```

at this point i am getting

```
<Application.ViewController: 0x105c200a0>
```

where `Application` is my actual application name, so i assume what i successfully accessed my `ViewController`, but when i try to call methods from it, for example

```
// ViewController.swift code
func getDictionaryValue(string: String) -> String {
    let dictionary = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!;
    let version = dictionary[string] as! String;
    return version;
}
```

like

```
// AppDelegate.swift code
controller.getDictionaryValue(string: "CFBundleDisplayName");
```

i am getting error `Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'getDictionaryValue'`

Comment: your ShitstuffController is no of  `UIViewController` class in fact is a `UIViewController` subclass which is `ViewController` so you need to cast to `ViewController` class `if let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShitstuffController") as? ViewController {
controller.loadViewIfNeeded();
controller.getDictionaryValue(string: "CFBundleDisplayName");
print(controller); } ` then you will be able to call `getDictionaryValue` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your **ShitstuffController** is not of  `UIViewController` class in fact is a `UIViewController` subclass which is `ViewController` so you need to cast to `ViewController` class

```
if let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShitstuffController") as? ViewController {
  controller.loadViewIfNeeded();
  controller.getDictionaryValue(string: "CFBundleDisplayName");
  print(controller); 
}
```

then you will be able to call `getDictionaryValue` method